# GraphQL Schema for edge that can be traversed in either direction

Tags: graphql

I own a data store, and am writing a GraphQL service/schema, and I am repeatedly running into a conceptual schema issue...

Let's say that I have two node types - user and mobile (phone).  Conceptually, I have always thought of the relationship as "user owns mobile", so my user object contains an "ownsMobile" edge that resolves to a list of mobiles (let's assume my users are rich enough to have more than one phone - I'm sure as heck not right now).

Since my data store can easily follow my "edge" in either direction, and my GraphQL service consumers may well want to query a mobile and retrieve its user, what should I call the field in the mobile type definition? Should it be "ownsMobile", since really I am following the same  "edge" in the opposite direction, or is it more correct to create a separate "ownedByUser" edge.

Or does it not matter that much, and I am tragically overthinking it (or even more tragically not understanding the concepts?)

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

`ownedByUser` make more sense, i'd even just use `ownedBy` (and `ownedMobiles` for the original relationship, the name should imply that it's an array).